# Compare mean value per night with value for each night, statistic validity?

Tags: r, validation, mean, lme4, statistical-sampling

I am using data from sites to examine the impact of different factors on site exit over several nights. I used minutes since sunset to study exit of bats from sites.

I want to look at the 5 nights before a disturbance and the 5 nights after the disturbance. I remove the Night of disturbance (Night0) of my analysis.

My question is : can I take the mean of my variable (minutes since sunset) for the 5 days before (natural variability) and then compare it with the outputs on Night+1, +2, +3, +4, and +5? **Is this statistically valid?**

I hesitate to use the mean of minutes since sunset and affect it to "before" factor, or stack all rows of the 5 nights before and affect it to "before" factor.

I hope my question is clear.

Thanks a lot for response

Comment: what does this have to do with `lme4` ... ???  The most natural way to handle this would be to use a **planned contrast**, either via `emmeans` or coding it yourself, that would compare (avg of before period) vs night 1, etc.

Comment: I'm currently edited my question because I use lme after, sorry

Comment: thanks @BenBolker, I used a lmer to compare levels of factor Nights (Ave of before vs Night +1, +2 ect...) but planned contrast is a very good idea. Note: I tested the difference of the 5 nights before and it showed no differences

Comment: @AlexanderGrimaudo's solution is more straightforward than setting up contrasts, although contrasts are more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't take the mean of the pre-disturbance nights, no. I would pool the raw data under a 'pre-disturbance' factor and then compare them to the 'night 1', 'night 2,' etc. pooled data. If you have more than one site, you'll need to incorporate a random effect. Also, given that your response is minutes until an event occurs, you need to use a gamma distribution. Below is code for how you might accomplish this in R and lme4:

```
library(lme4)

my.data$pool <- relevel(my.data$pool, ref="pre-disturbance")
#This is setting your model's reference level to the pre-disturbance pooled data. 
#When you run summary() on the model object, it will compare your daily disturbance 
#pools directly to the 'pre-disturbance' pool. 

model <- glmer(num.minutes ~ data.pool + (1|site), family=Gamma(link='log'), data=my.data)
#The model

summary(model)
```

Comment: A log-Normal  (`lmer(log(num.minutes) ~ ...)`) might also be fine, although I agree a Gamma is more natural.

Comment: I did exactly this model (with other variables) and incorporated Sites and Year as random effects. Can the number of observations in the 'pre-disturbance' modality influence the model? In fact, in the "pre-disturbance" we will have 5 times more data than in night 1, night 2 etc... modality of the Night factor.

Comment: Generalized linear mixed models do not assume equal sample sizes across factor levels. You should be fine just pooling all your raw, pre-disturbance data. It of course can 'influence' the model in terms of error estimates, but it's acceptable to do so.

Comment: Ok, that's great then, it confirms my analysis choices! I was afraid I'd have to add an offset or something. Thanks a lot for helping @AlexanderGrimaudo